# How to find counterexamples about independent event?

Tags: probability

I try to find counterexample that 'if $A,B$ are independent event and $A,C$ are independent event, then $A, B \cup C$ is independent.

I think it is false, because of
$P(A\cap(B\cup C)) = P((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)) = P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C) - P(ABC) =P(A)P(B) + P(A)P(C) - P(ABC)$

and $P(A)P(B \cup C) = P(A)[P(B)+P(C)-P(BC)] = P(A)P(B) + P(A)P(C) - P(A)P(BC)$

,
so maybe $P(ABC), P(A)P(BC)$ is not equal. But i can find it. Someone help?

Comment: When you need to find counter examples, consider a small number of coins. Take $X_1,X_2$ two independent unbiased coins labeled with $+1$ on one side and $-1$ on the other side. $A=\{X_1=+1\}$ is independent of $B=\{X_2=+1\}$. Try a few things for event $C$ to find a conter-example

Comment: @jlewk Thx! I just find it!